# Is there a useful analogy for understanding why only NP languages allow IP transformations to perfect soundness?

Tags: interactive-proof-systems

I'm embarking on my first adventure into the world of interactive proofs (IPs). Reading through [Thaler's survey](https://people.cs.georgetown.edu/jthaler/ProofsArgsAndZK.html), I became interested in IP transformations with respect to error.

Since it's possible to transform an arbitrary IP with completeness error (≤ 1/3 [[FGM 89]](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-Completeness-and-Soundness-in-Interactive-Proof-F%C3%BCrer-Goldreich/f610d07eddcd986225b2ffa31da422fa4460aa9a)) into an IP with perfect completeness, I became curious whether it's possible to do the same for an IP with respect to soundness.

I came across this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4568299), for which I can only read the abstract. Supposedly it proves this is only possible with NP languages (a concept I am not familiar with).

I don't know when I'll be well-enough equipped to approach some these concepts with any kind of rigor. But, it feels like there should be some basic intuition that I might be able to access. Is there a useful analogy for understanding why only NP languages allow IP transformations to perfect soundness? Some kind of thought experiment?